# Converting from MD5 Legacy Auth System to CakePHP

Tags: php, security, cakephp, authentication, user-experience

I have a site which runs off an MD5 hashing scheme for passwords. As a way of supporting this legacy system, I've [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423352/disabling-security-salt-for-plain-md5-hashing-in-authcomponent) answer to manually override the login system for now. But this isn't really ideal, as MD5 is pretty much universally known to be awful at encryption. So in the interest of security, what's the best way to migrate users over to the safer CakePHP auth system without causing them undue grief?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585222/use-md5-for-password-has-in-auth-component-of-cakephp-2-x) (albeit lightly modified). Basically, it updates the user behind the scenes to use the new system if the current system doesn't match up with it.

```
/**
 *  Login method
 */
public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'homepage';
    // If the user is already logged in, redirect to their user page
    if($this->Auth->user() != null) {
        $this->redirect();
    } else {
        // If this is being POSTed, check for login information
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if($this->Auth->login($this->loginHelper($this->request->data))) {
                // Redirect to origin path, ideally

            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, try again');
            }
        }           
    }
}

/**
 *  Update password method
 *  @param array The user's data array
 *  @param Returns either a user object if the user is valid or null otherwise
 */
private function loginHelper($data) {
    $username = $this->data['User']['username'];
    $plainText = $this->data['User']['password'];

    $user = current($this->User->findByUsername($username));

    $salted = Security::hash($plainText, null, true);

    if ($salted === $user['password']) {
        return $user; // user exists, password is correct
    }

    $md5ed = Security::hash($plainText, 'md5', null);

    if ($md5ed === $user['password']) {
                $this->User->id = $user['id'];
        $this->User->saveField('password', $plainText);

        return $user; // user exists, password now updated to blowfish
    }

    return null; // user's password does not exist.
}
```